# Pointer to a void function

Tags: c, initialization, function-pointers, declaration

What is the correct way for declaring a pointer to a void function?

```
void reverseArray(int arraySize, int a[]){
}
```

One of my many attempts which I think is somewhat correct

```
void (*reversePtr)(int, int) = &reverseArray;
```

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? It is almost correct except the second parameter type.

Comment: See here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/void-pointer-in-c

Comment: @EugeneSh. warning: initialization of 'void (*)(int,  int)' from incompatible pointer type 'void (*)(int,  int *)' not sure what It means but this is what I kept getting

Comment: This exactly means that type mismatch of the parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second parameter of the function pointer has an invalid type. As the function is declared like

```
void reverseArray(int arraySize, int a[]);
```

then a pointer to the function will look ,like

```
void ( *reversePtr )( int, int[] ) = reverseArray;
```

or like

```
void ( *reversePtr )( int, int * ) = reverseArray;
```

Take into account that there is no need to use the address of operator in the initializer expression like `&reverseArray`. It is enough to write just `reverseArray` because a function designator used in expressions is converted to pointer to its type.

For example you could even write

```
void ( *reversePtr )( int, int * ) = *****reverseArray;
```

or

```
void ( *reversePtr )( int, int * ) = *&*&*&*&*&reverseArray;
```

Comment: Personally prefer the second, pointer notation, especially on answers for new C programmers, since it reinforces that you're passing a pointer and not the array itself